# syntax error - token ";" inserted before "variable name"

Tags: c, header, extern

I'm programming in C.  I'm getting the following error:

```
ctc E208: ["..\..\ECB\Include\ecb.h" 4/11] syntax error - token ";"
inserted before "u8_vTeethBeforeMissingTeeth1"
```

Here is what I have in the .h file:

```
#ifndef __ECB_H__
#define __ECB_H__

extern u8 u8_vTeethBeforeMissingTeeth1;
extern u8 u8_vTeethBeforeMissingTeeth2;

#endif /* __ECB_H__ */
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing in this section of code?

Comment: How does the code look like which includes this head file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trouble is that your header is not self-contained.  It relies on a type '`u8`' which is not defined here (and not defined in any of the other headers you've included before this).  You should include the header that defines '`u8`' in your 'ecb.h' header before declaring your 'missing teeth' variables.

Headers should be self-contained; if you need the services of the header, you should be able to include it without worrying about what else needs to be included.  The standard C headers do that for you - you should do it for yourself with your own headers.

Comment: Thanks a million, Jon.. Earlier I placed this comment in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess. You have #define u8 and that definition is wrong. It contains extra ; somewhere.

Comment: No; the compiler inserted the semi-colon as an attempt at error recovery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. The problem seemed to be with the declaration of u8. So I included the file that has a definition for u8, and its working correctly now.